# Highlight Color & Text Color

Tags: color, text, highlight

How do we avoid using the same highlight color as the text color?

For example: when you highlight a paragraph, the background color changes to draw attention to the paragraph, but what if the color of the paragraph is the same as the background color?

How could we avoid that? Can you guys give me some keywords?

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the ::selection css property. You can read more about it on W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp